# Calling a Controller function in another Controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller "user" in my codeigniter application. This controller has a function called `logged_user_only()`:

```
public function logged_user_only()
    {
        $is_logged = $this -> is_logged();
        if( $is_logged === FALSE)
        {
            redirect('user/login_form');
        }
    }
```

As this function calls another function called `is_logged()`, which just checks if the session is set, if yes it returns true, else returns false.

Now if i place this function in the begining of any function within same controller, it will check if the user is not logged, it will redirect to `login_form` otherwise continue. This works fine.
For example,

```
public function show_home()
    {
        $this -> logged_user_only();
        $this->load->view('show_home_view');
    }
```

Now I would like to call this `logged_user_only()` function in a function of another controller to check if the user is logged in or not?

PS. If this can not be done, or is not recommended, where should i place this function to access in multiple controllers? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not extend the controllers so the login method is within a MY controller (within the core folder of your application) and all your other controllers extend this.  For example you could have:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function is_logged()
    {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

and your main controllers could then extend this as follows:

```
class Home_Controller extends MY_Controller {
    public function show_home()
    {
         if (!$this->is_logged()) {
           return false;
         }
    }
}
```

For further information visit: <del>[Creating Core System Classes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)</del>

New link is here:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html?highlight=core%20classes

Answer (score 9):

Calling a controller from another is not possible with CI and not recommended.

Either move your `logged_user_only` into a helper or even better a core controller that you extend all of your controllers from (`MY_Controller`) see http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MY_Controller_-_how_to_extend_the_CI_Controller/

Answer (score 6):

just load user controller as library from your controller

```
function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->library('../controllers/user');
}
```

Now, call this function of user controller any where in your controller,

```
$this->user->logged_user_only();
```

Answer (score 0):

Function login in Controller Login

```
$data =array('username' => $this->input->post('username'), 'password' => $this->input >post('password')) $query = $this->db->get_where('usertable',$data)
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'logged_in' => TRUE,
            'role' => "user");
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('home');
    }
```

Function Construct in Controller user

```
if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE && $this->session->userdata('role') == "user") {} else {redirect('home');}
```