# codeigniter how to call function which resides in another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

One stupid question, I want to call from my admin_news controller function which resides in another controller Admin. FUnction name is `is_logged_in();`
admin.php

```
public function is_logged_in()
{
   ....
}


admin_news.php
public function __contruct()
{
   parent::__construct();
   //admin->is_logged_in();??
}
```

how can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: That method should be in a model or a helper, not a controller.

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647112/calling-a-controller-function-in-another-controller-in-codeigniter#answer-6647355

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a Controller function in another Controller in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647112/calling-a-controller-function-in-another-controller-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 6):

You will have to move that functionality somewhere else, Codeigniter's architecture doesn't allow multiple controller instances in one request. You have multiple options like using a common base class, libraries, helpers and so on.

I would recommend you to create your own `MY_Controller` base class (see [Extending Core Classes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)) and put your method there, like this:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    protected function is_logged_in() {
        // ...
    }  
}
```

Once you have it there you can call it like:

```
class AdminNews extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->is_logged_in();
    }
}
```