# Calling a function from a different controller - should I be using this?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I just realized I might be doing something that is not entirely according to the book.
Here is the issue as simple as I can make it.

I have a controller two controllers `public` and `private` In the `public` controller I have created a function for error reporting called `error` it requires `$problem` as it's argument. For example if `$problem` is set to `"access"` the function forwards the user to an error page that says "access denied". I am also calling this method from the `private` controller like this `$problem = "access"; redirect('error/'.$problem);`.

I guess I have two questions.

Is it OK if I call the function like this or should I rather copy the function and put it in the `private` controller?

Also, how does this even work without a reference to the controller that holds the function? I think it might be because my main controller is set to `public` so it knows to look for the function there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a Controller function in another Controller in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647112/calling-a-controller-function-in-another-controller-in-codeigniter)

Comment: I guess. Not really as much insight as I was looking for, but it makes sense. Thank you and apologies for the duplicate then.

Comment: No worries. However, there're couple of similar topics on SO.